# Why Isn't a Dynamic Variable Parsed Correctly When Injected Into a Custom Pipeline as Code Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In my company, I'm running a pipeline as code project in which my Jenkinsfile gets a dynamic IP from a shell script, and injects that into a PrivateIP environment variable. The next step invokes a custom (in-house developed) plugin that accepts a "servers" argument as IP(s), though supposedly does not parse it correctly, cause the error output indicates an unresolvable host.

I've echoed the PrivateIP variable immediately above the plugin step, and it definitely outputs the correct value.

The plugin works if given a hard-value for IP, but fails if given anything dynamic. Built-ins such as `dir` don't give similar problems. I haven't been able to get a hold of the plugin developer to report the issue, nor have I gotten any responses for my issue. Is this typical for custom plugins? I've seen some documentation in the [plugin developer docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/developer/plugin-development/pipeline-integration/#variable-substitutions) that suggests only the initial environment stage is respected in pipeline plugins, otherwise a `@StepContextParameter` is needed to get a contextual environment.

```
stage('Provision') {
      environment {
          PrivateIP = """${sh(
             returnStdout: true,
             script: '${WORKSPACE}/cicd/parse-ip.sh'
          )}"""
      }

      steps {
        echo "Calling Playbook. PrivateIP: ${PrivateIP}"

        customPluginName env: 'AWS',
        os: 'Linux',
        parameter: '',
        password: '',
        playbook: 'provision.yaml',
        servers: PrivateIP,
        gitBranch: '{my branch}',
        gitUrl: '{URL}',
        username: '{custom user}'
      }
    }
```

I'd expect the variable to be respected and execute an Ansible Playbook  successfully.

**Error**

> >>> fatal: [ansible_ssh_user={custom user}]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname **ansible_ssh_user={custom user}**: Name or service not known\r\n", "unreachable": true}

If this in-fact a default behavior of custom plug-ins (not necessarily a bug), what are the good work arounds?

Comment: Referencing an environment variable needs to be accessed from the `env` map, vis a vis `env.PrivateIP` and not `PrivateIP` inside your steps. Give that a try, since it sounds like that is failing based on your description.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Yeah, to my surprise, both `env.PrivateIP` and `PrivateIP` produce the same result. Maybe the interpreter falls back to checking system variables if it cannot find a variable locally.

Comment: Well it also appears that the `username` parameter might be utilized in the plugin where `servers` should be utilized. Alternatively, `servers` implies a map or an array. Maybe a String type is not allowed there?

Comment: @MattSchuchard It's possible (given some conditions), although I don't have access to the plugin code, so I've opened an internal issue for the developers to have a look. The `servers` parameter definitely accepts a string, cause I've got it to execute properly passing a hard-value in the form of `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. Thanks for the feedback, but I'll pass on this burden to our internal team.